# Using bootstrap-datetimepicker, specifically time, update values of multiple inputs on change?

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am using: https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#inline

I am trying to "sync" the value of a bootstrap-datetimepicker plugin with a hidden input.

```
<script>
// Initialise the time pickers, on load update the start_time_x_sync values
function initialiseTimePicker(pickerId) {
  // Initialise time pickers
  $(pickerId).datetimepicker({
    format:'hh:mm A',
    inline: true
  }).on('dp.change', function(e) {
    // Grab the time value
    var date = $(pickerId).data('date');
    // Populate the hidden inputs for php to process them
    var syncId = pickerId+'_sync';
    $(syncId).val(date);
  });
};
// Run it
$(function() {
  initialiseTimePicker("start_time_1");
  initialiseTimePicker("start_time_2");
};
</script>

<label for="start_time_1">START TIME 1</label><br/>
<div id="start_time_1"></div>
<input type="hidden" id="start_time_1_sync" name="00:00 AM" />

<label for="start_time_2">START TIME 2</label><br/>
<div id="start_time_2"></div>
<input type="hidden" id="start_time_2_sync" name="00:00 AM" />
```

This works out quite well because I have 2 inline time pickers however there is something that I am batting to understand here.

If I use only 1 input then each time I alter the `#start_time_1` value, hour/minute/am/pm then it will update `#start_time_1_sync` with the time value, e.g. 00:00 AM.

When I use 2 inputs and I try to alter the `#start_time_1` value, in `#start_time_1_sync` it shows the value for `#start_time_2` and seems to get stuck because it will never change after that. However, if at that point I change the value of `#start_time_2` then `#start_time_2_sync` gets the updated value of `#start_time_2` each time a change it made as is expected.

So, in this example, it works for 1 if there is only one, but if there is 2 it only works for the second one. If there is three then it only works for the third.

How can I get them all to work without losing my hair? Thanks in advance!

Edit:

Here is the docs for `dp.change`: https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Events/#dpchange

Comment: Wheres `cleanInputId` and `cleanDate` being set? show more.

Comment: @BG101 Thanks, have updated it now. It was an error in copying it over and shortening what I am working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As all are using the same function to initialise, the parameter `pickerId` passed in last will be the parameter all the `change` events will receive.

try using `this` within the `change`:-

```
function initialiseTimePicker(pickerId) {
  // Initialise time pickers
  $(pickerId).datetimepicker({
    format:'hh:mm A',
    inline: true
  }).on('dp.change', function(e) {
    // Grab the time value
    var date = $(this).data('date');
    // Populate the hidden inputs for php to process them
    var syncId = '#' + this.id +'_sync';
    $(syncId).val(date);
  });
};
```

and I assume you should be using `#` in the parameters?

```
initialiseTimePicker("#start_time_1");
initialiseTimePicker("#start_time_2");
```

Also, its worth looking into *closures*.

Comment: This makes perfect sense now :-) I am really a javascript noob, it's the fundamentals that I guess I am still lacking as this is a silly mistake and one that I have made before! Looking closer at the docs now I noticed `var date = e.date;` also works, however it will give the full date that is not format as per the initial format parameter so this way is best as requires less modification for the output. Thanks a million! Really, it's a big help as i've been battling for ages now -.-

Comment: Oh yes, you are indeed correct. In my example, I forgot to prefix the id's with #'s when firing the function.